# img tag being added onto an already open img tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Excuse the vague question title. Not entirely sure on how to word this.

Basically my issue stems from a bit of jquery in which when setting the data attr in the html the img tag shows some odd behavior as shown below.

```
<img src="images/gallery/
                <img src="/images/gallery/bob.png" class="thumbnail&quot; data="1">
" class="popupImage">
```

From what I am seeing is the class "popupImage" is not replacing the class "thumbnail" however the img tag nested in the outer img tag should be a seperate entity all together, my mind is baffled, and have been at this for hours and probably just need a new pair of eyes to look over it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

This is the full html code and jQuery code for the gallery.

If I can provide anymore information who needs it please ask and I shall try and give some more where possible.

HTML

```
<?php 
    $data = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `gallery_items` ORDER BY id ASC");

//display query results

    ?>  
    <br /><br />

    <?php

    foreach($data as $item)
    {
        echo "<a data='".$item['id']."' class='noStyle'>
                <img src='/images/gallery/".$item['image']."' class='thumbnail' data='".$item['id']."'>
            </a>";
    }

    if(count($data) < 1){
        echo "<p style='text-align: center;'><br /><br />No results found</p>";
    }

?>

<div class="image">
    <button class="prev" data="unset">&lt;</button>
        <img src='' class="popupImage">
    <button class="next" data="unset">&gt;</button>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".noStyle").click(function(){
    loadPopup($(this).attr("data"));
});     

offFocus();

function loadPopup(id){
    imgSrc = "/images/gallery/"+$("a[data='"+id+"']").html();

    $("div.background").fadeIn(400, function(){
        $(".popupImage").attr("src", imgSrc);
        $(".image").fadeIn(500);
        reFocus();
        setPrevNext($("button[data='"+id+"']"));
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        reFocus();
    });

    function reFocus(){
        $(".image").css({"left": (($(window).width()/2) - ($(".image").width()/2))+"px", "top": (($(window).height()/2) - ($(".image").height()/2))+"px"});
    };
}/*close loadPopup */

function setPrevNext(buttonObj){
    objects = $(".button");
    firstObj = $(".button:first");
    lastObj = $(".button:last");

    prev = undefined;
    next = undefined;

    if(buttonObj.attr("data") == firstObj.attr("data"))
        prev = lastObj;
    else
        prev = objects.eq(objects.index(buttonObj)-1);


    if(buttonObj.attr("data") == lastObj.attr("data"))
        next = firstObj;
    else
        next = objects.eq(objects.index(buttonObj)+1);

    $(".prev").attr("data", prev.attr("data"));
    $(".next").attr("data", next.attr("data"));

    //next = buttonObj.next("button").attr("data");
    //$(".next").attr("data", "next");
}

function offFocus() {
        $(".background").click(function(){
            $(".background").css({"display": "none"});
            $(".image").css({"display": "none"});
    });
};
```

Comment: This is your issue: `imgSrc = "/images/gallery/" + $("a[data='" + id + "']").html();` although I'm not sure what you're expecting that line of code to actually do.

Comment: Actually the issue lies within your php. Change this <img src='/images/gallery/".$item['image']."' class='thumbnail' data='".$item['id']."'> to $item['image'] and see what happens

Comment: What are you assigning to `imgSrc` in the first statement? `.html()` of anchors?

Comment: I agree with @RoryMcCrossan, `imgSrc = "/images/gallery/"+$("a[data='"+id+"']").html();` returns everything inside the <a> tag which is the full <img> element. You should instead be making it something like `imgSrc = "/images/gallery/"+$("a[data='"+id+"']").attr('data');` I think, to get the data value only. Or more simply just `imgSrc = "/images/gallery/"+id;`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan and Dave (Can't tag you in so crediting this way)
Thank you both for the help, hadn't thought about changing that.

I get really bad tunnel vision when I cant figure something out. 

So again, best answer go to you both.

Comment: All good, hope you get it worked out.